# How to send a request to a POST URL from asp.net mvc app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, single-sign-on

This is my first question to stackoverflow and I have been struggling with it for the past 2 days. I am working on asp.net mvc application and I m pretty new to it. I have a web app and now we are asked to add payment functionality to this app. from the service provider I got the url and they said its a post url and string format to send something like this.

```
 Field1*45005L00|FName*Jonathan|LName*Barley|AmtDue*1570|

Post URL :  https://www.sendpayments.com/Client/SSO/Home
```

the url is like this. So I m not sure how I need to proceed, so what i did was I did some research and found some code for sending a httpwebrequest. so I added a action method and added a form post action to the make payment button, which when clicked would go to the controller and invokes this sendrequest post method (the code I got from internet) however what happens is after I click on my button the code gets executed and I see a blank page with the following line on it. So not sure what is happening. The code is given here..do I need to do this from server or use jquery I m not sure at all. Please help.

System.Net.HttpWebResponse

```
public HttpWebResponse SendPostRequest(string data, string url)
    {
        data = "Field1*45005L00|FName*Jonathan|LName*Barley|AmtDue*1570|";

        url = https://www.sendpayments.com/Client/SSO/Home;

        //Data parameter Example
        //string data = "name=" + value

        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream());
        streamWriter.Write(data);
        streamWriter.Close();

        return (HttpWebResponse) httpRequest.GetResponse();
    }
```

Text Recieved

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function BrowseBack() {
            if (window.opener != undefined) {
                window.close();
                return;
            }
            history.back();
        }
    </script>
<link id="idStyleLink" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link runat="server" rel="icon1" href="images/favicon-med.ico" type="image/ico"/> <link runat="server" rel="icon" href="images/favicon-med.ico" type="image/x-icon"/><title>

</title></head>
<body class="td">
    <form method="post" action="./error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=%2fCustomer%2fSingleSignOn%2fIndex" id="form1" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="1Rqce+RHGBAZPZKT4DCc7DjqgZIT89HQWlkNktl6sFzFbIvRvk1K/vcj1stkpDLFOCoCvo592mkFaJxGRVVR1Zacgtig9wQ5jOf0qkhv+zLw21ilQ4Grn0Y5mwp7OB+L59sLd/pRxCuqSCSKL23yD/9qIQPMfi0uf5CSCZjROpNEVkzBqOjRFD5WmgGU9gfC9x/xQZ0Yg+fNWua8EuFz7YIC1xVh5cZVX/wPP2wW4iuvTjZ+vvOS20qW3jvCvfjHMusdkgz2biY0wIbWbe3wOgUmHNHAKBEXC4nLincjvtcDbmcLTDcd7xePRd339YZb6Oz8MI2IBc5sZxZs3KENbSeo8IhokTmu5AUWsC+whXuIzJ1NPGiIOBehJNo3kSj847ZvYznsZJvZmvzZN7Kt3OHC0po=" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="AB827D4F" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="" />
      <div id="Divdefaultmsg">    
        <b>We are sorry for this inconvenience but we are temporarily experiencing  technical difficulties, if the problem persists, please contact  Merchant Support at 877-981-3478.<br/> 

        </b>    
    </div>
    <div>    
           <span id="Label1"></span>
        <span id="lblerror"></span>

    </div>
    <br /> <div>
    <a id="browseback" href="javascript:BrowseBack();">Back</a></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

Its a CashPro Biller Gateways Standard Single Sign On

Comment: According to the response, I think URL you are posting is down or did not have web service *(the return is the default error page from ASP.Net Web Form site)*. Normally, Payment gateways have pretty good documentations. You might want to tag that gateway in your question.

Comment: Looks like the page is down: We are sorry for this inconvenience but we are temporarily experiencing  technical difficulties, if the problem persists, please contact  Merchant Support at 877-981-3478.

Comment: I cannot tag it because its not in the list so I edited my post to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the httpRequest.ContentType to "text/plain", or "text/plain; charset=UTF-8".

"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is used for sending key-value pairs, so the server might be trying to interpret the data as such.

If that doesn't work try using the Postman Chrome plugin to experiment with sending data to the API. Try different combinations of inputs under the 'Body' tab until you find something that works. That should help you choose the correct ContentType.

The trailing | symbol in the data could also potentially be causing a type conversion issue on the server side too, but it's really hard to tell without more specific error info.

Comment: there is no error as such..I just see a blank screen with this in the page   System.Net.HttpWebResponse. Also I m supposed to send an encrypted string of the above input string. Let me try what you just said and I ll update you.

Comment: Do you have an API reference document?

Comment: For debugging purposes insert this code before returning from the method:
var response = (HttpWebResponse) httpRequest.GetResponse();
var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
var description = response.StatusDescription;

What values are you getting for statusCode and description?

Comment: the response code and description I m getting are "OK". And in the response the URI its returning looks like the URL of an error path. its  this                                                                    https://www.sendpayments.com.com/error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Client/SSO/Home

Comment: try this to see if you're getting any text back: var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var text = sr.ReadToEnd();

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough information to be able to help you any further. I'd suggest you talk to the developers of the API you are trying to call. The API doesn't seem to be well put together. It looks like it's returning OK even when there's a error :-/  I also tried to navigate to the links but they don't work.

Comment: I have edited my post to add the text that I m getting

Comment: thanks for trying...also the links I gave here are not entirely correct since its a public place I cannot post the correct links here..I can send it to you if you d like to check